# Undefined reference to difftime64 when compiling static cURL with mingw64

Tags: curl, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to build a `static executable` for Windows embedding `cURL`:

- MinGW-64 (x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-win32/seh/))
- Pre-compiled CURL packages from [official website](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)

The experience is quite straight-forward until the link phase where I have one remaining `linker error`.

```
third-party\lib\static\curl-7.73\lib\libssh2.a(session.o):(.text+0x367): undefined reference to `__imp__difftime64'
```

This function seems to come from the `C standard library` and is originally named `difftime` (`<time.h>`). For a reason I don't understand, the symbol seems to have been renamed from `difftime` to `difftime64` when `session.o` was built.

I tried to copy a [function definition](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2152/) directly in my source code:

```
/* static __inline__ I don't want inline anymore                */
/*                   I want to export this function for libssh2 */
double _difftime64( __time64_t __t1, __time64_t __t0 )
{
  return (double)((long double)(__t1) - (long double)(__t0));
}

// I also tried to name the function "difftime64", "_difftime64" and "__difftime64"
// With the same results
```

Unfortunately, this naive approach does not work and the `linker error` remain. Is there a way to rename to `session.o` import name with `bintutils` or a way to tell the linker that `difftime64` is actually `difftime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a standalone build of the latest version of MinGW-64 from [winlibs.com](http://winlibs.com/).

Comment: I just tried, but unfortunately the linker error remains.

Comment: Could you try with a newer MinGW/GCC?
You can get a standalone build of the latest version from http://winlibs.com/.

Comment: With the given toolchain, it works perfectly! Thank you very much, I was thinking I got a very recent GCC toolchain, but you let me figure out a much up to date toolchain!